# How to sync data from Azure SQL managed instance to On-premise SQL server instance on weekly Basis

Tags: scheduled-tasks, database-migration, data-synchronization

Please what are the options for me in the following scenario.

We have a SQL managed instance on Azure, our client has requested that they want their data (managed instance) to sync on a weekly basis with their on premise SQL server. I suggested using Azure Data Sync but that will be costly for us and using transactional replication based on what was described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/managed-instance/replication-transactional-overview?view=azuresql is also costly as it requires that we have another managed instance to act as a broker.

Please, I'm very welcoming to ideas you may have on how to go about this.

Thank you.

Comment: I've gotten a bit far, I did an SSIS package